# Генерация индивидуальных Url

Tags: веб-программирование, php, java

Всем привет. Не смог найти ни одного обьяснения.
Опишу кейс: Есть сайт, я захожу, ввожу данные, получаю результат, в url появляется какая-то лапша, я могу скопировать, отправить ее кому-нибудь и у него это откроется. Как это генерится и как он находит это?

Comment: Попробуйте немного конкретизировать вопрос.

Вам непонятно, почему при переходе по http://hashcode.ru/questions/289392/php-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-url пользователь попадает на эту страницу?

Comment: Тут более менее ясно, тут есть паттерн, я когда писал, говорил о полной лапше. Хотя и тут не освсем ясно.

В данном случае можно в контроллере получить url, разобрать его и выдать нужный вопрос - я бы так это сделал.

Не ясно как быть с полной лапшей, которая не поддается паттернам(на первый взгляд)

Comment: Может хоть какой-то пример?

Comment: Может на основании данных, генерируется хэш, возможно с солью, и он и есть эта лапша?

Comment: Минусовать не буду, но вообще не понял в чем суть вопроса, что за такое чудо "индивидуальные Url? действительно, может сможете примерчик какой-нибудь придумать!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если в "Лапше" не содержится какой либо информации кроме "лапши", то скорее всего просто генерится уникальная последовательность в виде "лапши", а на сервере привязывается к ней вся нужная для отображения информация.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в урле и есть тот самый контент который отображается на странице, просто он закодирован в базе 64 и передается в качестве параметра

Comment: зачем тогда сайт, если мы пересылаем данные напрямую?

Comment: сайт выводит данные из парметра на страницу

Comment: так можно абсолютно любой контент генерировать и храниться он будет на стороне клиента

Comment: отличная схема

Comment: например можно сделать сайт поздравительных открыток, выбираешь картинку в интернете, пишешь текст, полученый html запихиваешь в параметр строки и получается уникальный контент